# how can i add functioning to the button for one click and for next click it should be disabled in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

here iam attaching my code  tell me that how button perform function and disable immediately until it refreshed  and also i have to set timer for it

please help how to do this  and i have different sizes of tables to perform so when one button is performing some other button should not work

```
<html>
   <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

                function boardSize(id, btnid) {

            function hitheadr(id, btnid) {

                return function () {
                    console.log(id);
                };
                 document.getElementByid(btnid).disabled=true;
            }`
            function createTable(rows, cols, element) {
                function getButtonId(i, j) {
                    return 'hit'
                }
               var table = document.createElement('table'),
                    tr, td, button, i, j,
                    colors = ["red", "blue", "yellow"];

                for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                    tr = document.createElement('tr');

                    for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                        td = document.createElement('td');
                        button = document.createElement('button');
               button.style.backgroundColor  =colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
                        button.appendChild(document.createTextNode(getButtonId(i, j)));
                        button.onclick = hitheadr(getButtonId(i, j));
                        button.id = getButtonId(i, j);
                        button.onclick = onBtnClick;

                                               button.id = getButtonId(i, j);
                        td.appendChild(button);
                        tr.appendChild(td);
                    }
                    table.appendChild(tr);
                    table.setAttribute("align", "center");
                    tr.setAttribute("border", "2");
                }
                element.appendChild(table);
            }

            createTable(3, 3, document.body);
        }

    </script> 
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

With this following code you may able to disable the button click.
once button is clicked this script will disable your next button click until you refresh the page.

```
            function boardSize(id, btnid) {

        function hitheadr(id, btnid) {

            return function () {
                console.log(id);
            };
             document.getElementByid(btnid).disabled=true;
        }`
        function createTable(rows, cols, element) {
            function getButtonId(i, j) {
                return 'hit'
            }
           var table = document.createElement('table'),
                tr, td, button, i, j,
                colors = ["red", "blue", "yellow"];

            for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                tr = document.createElement('tr');

                for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                    td = document.createElement('td');
                    button = document.createElement('button');
           button.style.backgroundColor  =colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
                    button.appendChild(document.createTextNode(getButtonId(i, j)));
                    button.onclick = hitheadr(getButtonId(i, j));
                    button.id = getButtonId(i, j);
                    button.onclick = onBtnClick;

                                           button.id = getButtonId(i, j);
                    td.appendChild(button);
                    tr.appendChild(td);
                }
                table.appendChild(tr);
                table.setAttribute("align", "center");
                tr.setAttribute("border", "2");
            }
            element.appendChild(table);
        }

        createTable(3, 3, document.body);
    }

</script>
```